# How do I split or slice everything only inside in the bracket and still loop through?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to split and slice this text when given a string like this:

```
big_str = "[41.386263640000003, -81.494450689999994]    6    2011-08-28 19:02:28    yay. little league world series!\n[42.531041999999999, -82.90854831]    6    2011-08-28 19:02:29    i'm at holiday inn express suites & hotel roseville mi (31900 little mack ave., at masonic blvd., roseville)\n[39.992309570000003, -75.131119729999995]    6    2011-08-28 19:02:29    @_tweetthis what dorm r you in?\n[54.104106119999997, 28.336019929999999]    6    2011-08-28 19:02:29    @andykozik круто !!!\n[25.787949600000001, -80.132949600000003]    5    2011-09-03 05:40:14    pizza rustica #ftw"
```

I did that with this code:

```
def getLatitude(l):
  for x in l:
    y = list(x.split("\t"))
    for h in y:
        j = list(h.split("]"))
        w = j[0]
        x = len(w)/2
        v = w[1:x-1]
        z = float(v)
        return z
        continue

def getLongitude(x):
  y = list(x.split("\t"))
  w = y[0]
  x = len(w)/2
  v = w[x+1:-1]
  z = float(v)
  return z

def getGpsPixelX(x):
  y = (getLongitude(x) + 180) * 500.0/360
  return y

def getGpsPixelY(y):
  x = 500 - ((getLatitude(y) + 180) * 500.0/360)
  return x

line_list = big_str.split("\n")
getGpsPixelY(line_list)
```

I only need the numbers in the bracket to be returned to the `getGpsPixel` `X` or `Y` so I tried splicing and splitting but it sometimes shows an error on the get Latitude function when I put two splits...and not only that but it will only give the value of the first line and not the other lines of the posts. I'm not sure why since it is a for loop...

Comment: Where/how is that string generated? The problem is there; can you change it?

Comment: It would normally be coming from a get file text from computer. I just took a few lines and placed it in the big_str variable

Comment: I'm not sure what a "get file text" is. Is that a typo, or perhaps should you be reading it as a tab-delimited CSV?

Comment: I'm a bit lost on this, I'm assuming you're reading the file in python too so can you post that code? Reading a file format incorrectly and then using regex to break the input back down isn't a great design

Comment: Oh I was meaning like a f.read from a text file. I took a small version of it from that file and placed it in big_str. (Sorry only a beginner at this...was that what you were asking?)

Comment: That's fine. What is the file extension? (E.g. `.txt`, `.csv` etc.)?

Comment: It's .txt file.

Comment: And you're on Windows and didn't generate this file yourself (deliberately making some assumptions)?

Comment: Your big string doesn't contain any tab characters, so why is your code doing a `x.split("\t")`?

Comment: Ya I didn't generate this txt file. It was a file already made from previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex:

**Ex:**

```
import re
import ast
big_str = "[41.386263640000003, -81.494450689999994]    6    2011-08-28 19:02:28    yay. little league world series!\n[42.531041999999999, -82.90854831]    6    2011-08-28 19:02:29    i'm at holiday inn express suites & hotel roseville mi (31900 little mack ave., at masonic blvd., roseville)\n[39.992309570000003, -75.131119729999995]    6    2011-08-28 19:02:29    @_tweetthis what dorm r you in?\n[54.104106119999997, 28.336019929999999]    6    2011-08-28 19:02:29    @andykozik круто !!!\n[25.787949600000001, -80.132949600000003]    5    2011-09-03 05:40:14    pizza rustica #ftw"
res = []
for i in re.findall(r'\[.*?\]', big_str):
    res.extend(ast.literal_eval(i))
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[41.38626364, -81.49445069, 42.531042, -82.90854831, 39.99230957, -75.13111973, 54.10410612, 28.33601993, 25.7879496, -80.1329496]
```

Comment: What is re.findall? Sorry I'm only a beginner at this. How would I put that in just the latitude and longitude functions so that the get pixel functions can call for it and use it when it's needed?

Comment: @Jasmines: Time you learned about regular expressions (regex's), but somewhere else—SO isn't a tutorial site.